# How to migrate a WebYep website to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, import, web, migration, content-management-system

I had a website which was built using the CMS WebYep. Now I want to shift it to WordPress. Can anyone tell me how to do that?
Thanks is advance :)
Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no automatic process for most CMS.

You can either do it manually, or write a program (or hire somebody to write it) to help do the job.

In most cases the manual way is preferred. Different content management systems work quite differently, so there's usually not a universal way to set things up. Recognizing the differences and how to achieve a similar result is an easy thing to do for a human but a very hard thing to do for a computer. Plus, from my experience, with a relaunch usually comes a re-structuring. When you're moving to a new house, you might just get rid of that old broken sofa while you're at it, basically.

When you have a very large website with lots of similar content, a developer can certainly write scripts to aid in the process of moving your content over to WP. This will usually not be cheap, so it's not a smart idea for a site that consists of a dozen pages or where the content isn't very homogenous.

Comment: I was wondering like the plug-ins: 
All-in-One WP Migration
WP Migrate DB
If there could be some easy method. Like the Plug-ins or if i could download the files from ftp and upload it to WordPress.

Comment: No, that (and most other plugins in that category) is meant to migrate WP sites from one server to another, not migrate from one CMS to WP or the reverse.